# JqGrid custom search toolbar event handlers

Tags: events, search, jqgrid

I have created a jqGrid grid with a drop down list, this list (due to dev restraints) needs to be loaded once, so that all data returned can be filtered, all this is cool so far,

The problem arrives when the drop down list is changed, though the majority of the filtering/searching is done client-side, I need the drop down list to trigger a call that will refresh the page using the newly added parameter from the drop down list.

I have enclosed the section of code that builds the toolbar search, but I have no idea how to add the functionality to catch the event handler when changing the select value, in this only instance I need a non-standard code to be executed - e.g function callNewData()

```
colNames:["Rent Due Date ","Tenant","Description","Address","Payment Ref.","Rent     Amount","Outstanding","Amount     Received","Confirm?","tenancyID","tenantID","rentID","existingRent"],
    colModel :[{
        name:"rentDueDate", 
        index:"rentDueDate", 
        align:"center", 
        width:"130", 
        search:true, 
        stype:"select",
        searchoptions: {
            value: "all:All;due:Due;overdue:Overdue;future:+1 Week;" ,
            defaultValue:"due"
        }
    },
```

Where in the search options (or in the colModel) would I put the onChange event Handler?

Comment: How are you changing the values in the drop down list presently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but it's unclear what your exact problem. If the user choose an option from the drop-down list then jqGrid **automatically** reload the grid with the filter which user have chosen. If you use local `datatype` then the filtering will done by jqGrid internally. If you use `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` without usage `loadonce: true` then jqGrid send request to the server appending information about the filter to the list of standard parameters.

If you really need to handle `onChange` event in the `<select>` then you need define `change` event handler inside of `dataEvents`:

```js
searchoptions: {
    value: "all:All;due:Due;overdue:Overdue;future:+1 Week;",
    defaultValue: "due",
    dataEvents: [ 
        {
            type: "change",
            fn: function (e) {
                // some code which will be executed onChange
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, its taken a whlle to look into but the upshot is that if a date is selected from the drop[ down in the toolbar then the grid needs to be reloaded from the server side and not from the JSON stored data, anyother filtering/searching can be done with the standard client side stuff.  It is preventing the search/filter excuting a client side search if chosen, I am sure that the dataevent example above would do it as I can just reset the querystring with the new date and reload the page, anyother column will act normally

Comment: @Jimmyborofan: One can see indirectly from your last comment, that the code which you posted in your question **contains not the origin of your problem**. It seems that you use `loadonce: true`, but you use it in the wrong way. You should append the text of your question with more JavaScript code. It's important that you'll describe additionally what functionality you implemented in the server side: sorting, paging, filtering. It's also important the you'll write how large are the full data (all paged, not filtered) which you shows in jqGrid (100, 1000, 10000, 100000 or more).

Comment: HI thanks for the reply after a lot of trying I ran out of time and had to move the refresh outside of jQgrid, which sucked a lot because ten minutes after I committed I went over it after a code review and saw how to use dataevent correctly which was a little annoying, Ive been put on another project for now but its in my list of things to go back over ;)

Comment: @Jimmyborofan: You are welcome! If you have new problem in new project you can ask *new question* where you describe the problem in details. The usage of `dataEvents` is very simple. It specify *array* of events which you need register. So you can register for example `change` and `keydown` events on one `<select>`.